# XSLTProcessor.importStylesheet() - допустимые параметры

Tags: javascript, xslt

Смотрел документацию https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor. Использую Chrome последней версии. Как правильно скормить указанной в заголовке функции файл.xsl, если известен путь к нему на диске сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. трансформация будет производится на клиенте (чего лично я настоятельно не рекомендую делать), то XML и XSL файлы должны быть доступны клиенту. Сервер их может отдать по протоколам http/https/WebSocket.... Метод `XSLTProcessor.importStylesheet()` принимает параметр `Node`.

Т.е. Вам нужно

1. получить XSL файл
2. Загрузить его в `Document`
3. Отдать полученный объект в `importStylesheet`

В приведенной Вами ссылке есть и пример использования

```js
var myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "example1.xsl", false);
myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);

xslStylesheet = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);
```

Comment: open false - фууууууу

Comment: @Qwertiy у человека был конкретный вопрос. Давайте в ответе прикрутим еще асинхронность, поддержку всех браузеров и уведомления об ошибках прокси-серверов

Comment: Асинхронность, которая тут должна быть, прикручивается за 30 секунд. Зачем вместо этого учить делать плохо?

Comment: @Qwertiy научите хорошо. И постарайтесь при этом не усложнить понимание ответа